# copy Product.code and paste it into Product.description and Product.name for all Products using impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

So, yeah. That's the task. How do I achieve this copying thing? I'd appreciate ur help, I'm a newbie in Hybris.

Comment: You want to do that one time or on a regular basis? During a product import?

Comment: one time. yeah.

Comment: Run SQL query through HAC and you are done!!

Comment: oh, I forgot to specify, I need to do this using impex.

Comment: Step `1.` export product code as impex  `2.` covert impex to excel `3.` add two more column with same value `4.` convert excel to impex and import it

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions so you will be better prepared and able to ask a question that will be well received and more importantly **answerable**. This is not a *send me teh codez* site, that is now how this site works.

Answer (score -1):

In general it is possible to include SQL data in you impex file. You need to know, of course, your DB url, user and pass and the driver. You can find these properties in your local.properties file under /config. This this script should do the tick (**Not tested, so you may have to modify it a little bit**)

```
UPDATE Product;pk[unique=true];name;description
#% impex.initDatabase( <dburl>, <user>, <password>, <driver.class>);
"#%
   impex.includeSQLData(
   "" SELECT o.pk,o.code,o.code FROM products  AS o) ""
   );
"
```

More info you can find in the [wiki](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/2fb5a2a780c94325b4a48ff62b36ab23.html#loio2fb5a2a780c94325b4a48ff62b36ab23)